# creating SQL CREATE TABLE query in R

Tags: r, string

I have two vectors of column names and column types for SQL table. I would like to parse these to CREATE TABLE query and run it from R to automatically create tables. Here is example:

```
DATA:
    col_names <- c("id", "integer", "decimal", "varchar", "logical")
    col_types <- c("int", "int", "decimal(10,4)", "varchar(255)", "int")
```

SQL CREATE TABLE query looks like following:

```
"CREATE TABLE test_tbl ( colname1 coltype1, colname2 coltype2, ... )"
```

This can then be run with dbSendQuery from odbc package.

My solution but cumbersome is following and I would like to find easier way to parse names and types to that query format. My tables are getting larger and I don't think it is smart to do my solution for 50+ columns.

```
paste0("CREATE TABLE db_tbl ( ", 
                        col_names[1], " ", col_types[1], ", ",
                        col_names[2], " ", col_types[2], ", ",
                        col_names[3], " ", col_types[3], ", ",
                        col_names[4], " ", col_types[4], ", ",
                        col_names[5], " ", col_types[5], " )")

"CREATE TABLE db_tbl ( id int, integer int, decimal decimal(10,4), varchar varchar(255), logical int )"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paste` within `paste0`

```
paste0("CREATE TABLE db_tbl ( ",paste(col_names, col_types, collapse = ","), ')')

#[1] "CREATE TABLE db_tbl ( id int,integer int,decimal decimal(10,4),varchar varchar(255),logical int)"
```